# FET Drive for 200A Battery Charger Question

Tags: mosfet, charger

I have 12V, 650A-hr house batteries I want to charge from the alternator when traveling.  The alternator has a continuous rating of 240A @ 14.6V.  The alternator regulator drops the voltage some.

The charger will be 3 stage, max 200A (by shunt feedback).  I will sometimes want to operate the FETS at less than "full on", somewhere is the 4 - 8Vgs range.  When I do this, the voltage out to the house battery will be lower and the battery will accept fewer amps.  At Vout = 13.2V, the house batteries will be float charging, consuming about 10A total.

Because this is a one-off product, the additional cost for FET count overkill is not an issue, nor is the cost for generous heat sinks and multiple NTC temperature sensors (not shown) that I will attach to the FET copper bus bars.

I am seeking comments whether the attached circuit will work for what I intend?
[image]

Comment: Why not throttle the alternator in various ways (control the generator RPM, control field yourself i.e. replace the internal regulator)? Saves a huge pile of trouble trying to make a linear regulator circuit. Alternately, you might as well double down on complexity and make a multi-phase interleaved buck converter; switching gives high efficiency.

Comment: Messing with my engine's alternator is out of the question for me.  I did investigate buck/boost converter, but quickly gave up.  The first obstacle was specifying and obtaining the necessary inductor.  Also, not particularly interested in doubling down on complexity. I'm not an EE.  The topology of the brute force back to back P and N FETS is pretty simple to understand.  It's the implementation of the FET drive I am asking about.

Comment: The problem is more rudimentary than you think: as shown, you've drawn the PMOS backwards, so that the alternator is dumped into the battery regardless of control, through the body diode (which these symbols show twice: the triangle in the middle is the channel-substrate (body) diode structure, and the parallel diode reinforces this symbolically). Correcting for this, you still have no means of enforcing sharing between devices: naively in parallel, one will take almost all the current, and overheat in a runaway condition; nor implementing proportional control.

Comment: You may still find a charge controller unit for such ratings, and power input; or perhaps you are willing to contract someone for design of this. But I would suggest playing to your strengths, and finding the simplest possible solution, whether mechanical or electrical. For example, simplest of all would be to find an alternator that simply can't supply more than the specified current, and just accept that you won't have adjustable range (it's always set at max; but no more than that).

Comment: Explaining in more detail what you want that cct to accoplish would help. I do not know what the NFETS are for or how they function. || Without feedback cointyrolling that cct in otyher than off on is not viable (once actual cct issues are corrected). || I'd prtefer an off / on contyroller with either a capacitor to smooth the mean effective switch resistance OR makje it a buck regulator with an inductor and diode. That is less hard than you may imagine and FETs are MUCH better treated. Inductor can be hand wound on an old eg microwave over transformer core or ... .

Comment: The N fets body diode will prevent charging when the FETs are off. The P fets prevent back feeding.  Buck converter is out of the question due to insufficient voltage headroom.   PWM  into caps doesn't work for two reasons,  1. Without a large inductor,  capacitors would be enormous,  and 2. Duty cycle will be at or near 100% at 200A,.  With the Fets I have chosen,  total losses are 50W, 40 across the Pfets, 10 across the Nfets, if they share equally.   Because of the sheer number, they will be close to equal,  at least according to a technical paper from infinion on // fets.

Comment: The question is whether the proposed gate driver is sufficient assuming continuous conduction.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'm going to breadboard with a number of single fets from same lot, characterize them and make a decion whether to proceed based on the testing.

Comment: @BarryJensen  You can help FETs load share by having a small amount of resistance in the source leads. How small is small may need design. eg at 250A and 10 FETS if Rdson is 5 mV genuine (so spec somewhat lower) then at 25A/FET the d-s drop = V=IR =~ 25 x 0.005 = 0.125V and about 3 Watts per FET ) Just by arranging traces on a PCB (if used) or wires to not hard join at the sources but have a small trace length from each FET befoe they join you will quite likely be able to achieve current sharing. This is NOT adding extra resistance - just distributing it differently. ||

Comment: @BarryJensen  At these current a relay may be worth considering.

Comment: You have 50mOhm Rds on to get 1.25V drop, should be closer to 5mOhm?  I will limit current to 20A/NFET average.  Assuming highest current FET is 20% more than lowest current FET, that puts highest current FET at about 24A, so I agree there.  dVfet=IR = 24 x 0.005 = 0.12V.  P = VI = 1.4W/FET.  I planned to bolt or solder TO-220 FET Drains to substantial bus bar 1"x1/4" as primary heat sink.  Drains routed to 2nd bus bar by short wire.  The bus bar temp rise will be <2C in free air at 200A total.  All this for the NFETS.  PFET losses are higher even with twice the number of FETS.

Comment: With back to back PFETs and NFETs the Voltage drop will be about 0.3-0.4V at 200A.  Based on my RV's Inverter/Charger data while charging the batteries, I doubt the batteries will accept 200A with this design's hard on performance and an output voltage of 14.1V and batteries at 50% State of Charge.  It will be a close call.  200A is about 0.3C for the batteries which is well below the max C according to the Lifeline, the battery manufacterer.

Comment: I have the DC contactor available to me.  Contactor allows no option for multi-stage charging and that is why I have been avoiding its use.  It would be a cheap try for bulk and possibly absorption charging however.  I think I will give it a try, monitoring the batt volts and current and disconnect when battery volts/current deviates above battery recommended profile.

Comment: @BarryJensen You are right - I used .05 but intended .005 Ohms Rdson :-(. That would be a FET specd at maybe 0.003 Ohms in continuious non-pulse worst case mode. || That makes the dissipation very bearable for TO220's . || My relay comment was intended only for the N Fets - I should have made that clear. The losses are not too bad - maybe 15-25 Watts. A contactor coil will use some of that.